# Use BCrypt hashing function in Spring Boot without all the overkill security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bcrypt

I have a Spring Boot project with SQL/Web dependencies. I have controllers and models but NO configuration classes. This is  a very simple project so I'm doing simple authentication by checking user-specific tokens in the request headers. I would like to use the BCrypt dependency to hash passwords before saving them into my database, but Spring Boot won't let me simply use the static functions.

I have added these three dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And created an endpoint in my controller just to check the output of the static hashpw function.

```
@GetMapping("/bcrypt/{pw}")
public String crypt(@PathVariable String pw)
{
    return BCrypt.hashpw(pw, "xxwv");
}
```

But now that I added those 3 dependencies, it keeps redirecting me to a login page that I never created. I just want to use the static hashing functions without Spring Boot adding random security I never asked for.

Comment: is all of the dependencies are required, just to do encryption?

Answer (score 13):

Adding following exclude parameter to the annotation of my Application class solved the problem:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```